# How can we use latest angular version plugin with Hawtio?

Tags: angular, hawtio

Latest Hawtio v1.5.9 war comes with angularjs v1.1.5. How can we use latest angular with it? Could not find any example for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "latest angular"?  Is it Angular 2+ or latest AngularJS 1.x?

Comment: Angular 2+.....

Answer (score 0):

At this moment hawtio doesn't support Angular 2+ and will not likely in the near future. hawtio v1 (1.5.x) uses an older version of AngularJS 1.x. The next version of hawtio -- hawtio v2, which is still in beta but will be GA soon -- uses the up-to-date version of AngularJS (1.6.9), but there is no plan to migrate hawtio to Angular 2+ yet.